# Bucket finding algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

A question I got on my last interview:

Suppose you have 16 buckets.First 5 buckets are red in color,next 7 are blue,next 2 are green and next 2 are yellow.In Every bucket there is ball and some number is printed on them.Ball may not be in right bucket.So our task is to call function bucket() which returns bucket color and move them into correct bucket.

Function bucket():

```
It will scan the ball and according to scanned number it will return color. 
if number is between 0 to 4 then it will return red.
if number is between 5 to 8 then it will return blue.
if number is between 9 to 12 then it will return green.
if number is between 13 to 16 then it will return yellow.
```

you can use some temporary non colored buckets to move balls from one bucket to other but it should be less than 9 bucket.

you have two function to move ball from one bucket to other.

**pick:** you can take the ball from bucket.

**place:** you can place the ball in bucket.

you need to find minimum no of pick and place operation require to complete job in worst,best and average case.you can take few pass over buckets.(you can assume that all function will take o(1) time.)

Example:

```
|5| |3| |4| |7| |8| |2| |5| |6| |12| |10| |13| |1| |7| |14| |0| |7|
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |    |    |    |   |   |   |    |   |
|R| |R| |R| |R| |R| |B| |B| |B|  |B|  |B|  |B| |B| |G| |G|  |Y| |Y|
```

Output:

```
|0| |3| |4| |1| |2| |8| |5| |6| |5| |7| |7| |7| |12| |10| |14| |13|
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |    |     |   |
|R| |R| |R| |R| |R| |B| |B| |B| |B| |B| |B| |B| |G|  |G|   |Y| |Y|
```

**Note:** output order may differ but they should be in range.
for example here in red bucket ball are [0,3,4,1,2] but one may get order like [1,4,2,3,0].It doesn't matter what order you get till they are in specified range.Here as you can see range is 0 to 4 for red.

you can not store more than one ball in a bucket.

**Generalize version:** There is N, K colored bucket and using Function bucket() move them into correct buckets.you can use only than 2*K non colored buckets.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't think I understand this question. Why wouldn't you always just move each ball directly into the corresponding bucket?

Comment: I told her that I will put pointer at start of every color.I will start with red and if it is in correct bucket then I will increment pointer otherwise suppose it belongs to green bucket then take that ball in non colored bucket and I will go to green pointer and check for ball which does not belongs to green and take it in non colored bucket and put previous non colored ball tn green bucket.Now I will try to find correct bucket for non colored bucket ball.this cycle will end when we found correct red ball and this way in end we will end up putting all balls in correct bucket

Comment: @templatetypedef sorry I forgot to mention that in question."you can not store more than one ball in a bucket".

Comment: Is there anything stopping us from basically implementing a selection sort using one extra non-colored bucket?

Comment: @AndyG you end up calling Function bucket() o(n^2).Now time complexity will become o(n^2).The solution I mentioned in comment require only two passes.

Comment: @user3811315: Your post does not indicate a desired time/space complexity.

Comment: @AndyG I hope it is clear now.

Comment: So average case complexity should be `O(n)`? Am I reading that correctly? What does "Best case complexity" mean to you, and is it different than `O(1)` (all balls are already in correct buckets)?

Comment: @AndyG  you need to find way to minimize no of pick and place operation require to complete job in worst,best and average case.Have you heard of dutch flag problem.Time complexity is always going to be O(N) with some constant factor  or we can say we have to minimize constant factor associated with O(N). http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Sort/Flag/